# Why when I use class1: focus .class not working but with class1:focus ~ .class they work?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create 1 search menu. With the search history that will appear when I click input search box

When I use `class:focus ~ .class2`, they work ? Please show me how we work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
.header__search-input:focus  .header__search-input-history {
    display: block;
}

.header__search-input-history {
    display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header__search-input-wrap">
    <input type="text" class="header__search-input" placeholder="Search">
    <div class="header__search-input-history">
     <h3 class="header__search-input-history-title">History Search</h3>
     <ul class="header__search-input-history-list">
         <li class="header__search-input-history-item">
         <a class="header__search-input-history-link" href="">History Item</a>
         </li>
         <li class="header__search-input-history-item">
         <a class="header__search-input-history-link" href="">History Item</a>          </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope my answer helps. You may get faster responses in the future if you adjust your question titles to be more generalized e.g. "How can I toggle a sibling element based on input focus?"

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css. This makes use of the + sibling selector

```
.header__search-input-history{
  display: none;
}

.header__search-input:focus + .header__search-input-history
{
    display: block;
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/jriches/pen/QWveZqW